# Where does Linux get Swap partitions to mount

Tags: linux, swap

I have recently added a second swap partition for my third system (Two of which are Linux).

My aim was to have a single dedicated swap space for each of the systems so that it would not cause any problems when swap-sharing.

Making the appropriate changes to /etc/fstab, I rebooted... Only to have the first system load both of the available swap partitions.

My question is, are there any other ways a system can mount a partition other than those listed in `/etc/fstab`?

`cat /etc/fstab` output

```
UUID=9034-ACC1  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
UUID=ece74c78-21b5-4c37-ad97-2dcbd98c1d50 /home           ext4    defaults        0       2
UUID=78ab45f8-1a54-49b3-b7a9-48afc6a95054 none            swap    sw              0       0
/dev/sr0        /media/cdrom0   udf,iso9660 user,noauto     0       0
UUID=de651abc-dcc4-472a-8bb6-64d0e89cdc30 /tmp ext4 defaults,noauto 0 2
UUID=f5019f7b-d758-4aee-8261-424ca5813b75 /var ext4 defaults,noauto 0 2
UUID=477bf58b-c602-4116-afea-7e8914adbf56 / ext4 errors=remount-ro,noauto 0 1
```

Yet `cat /proc/swaps` yields

```
Filename                Type        Size    Used    Priority
/dev/sda15              partition   6291452 0       -2
/dev/sda8               partition   6179836 0       -1
```

`fdisk -l`

```
Disk /dev/sda: 931.5 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: E7779D9B-ADD0-40D7-A257-C1DEF6AC0E35

Device     Type                         UUID
/dev/sda1  Windows recovery environment 84D97802-5484-4905-85D5-39A6C394635F
/dev/sda2  EFI System                   FF3F087C-3E1F-428B-A3A6-3083444059F9
/dev/sda3  Microsoft reserved           0BE8D02B-398F-4D93-9A71-8C1AE98FBF20
/dev/sda4  Microsoft basic data         8F0537C3-D0CF-413C-9417-FA2436FF1583
/dev/sda5  Windows recovery environment 7CC71CC6-F1D9-4693-AB32-5DB177867815
/dev/sda6  Linux filesystem             A20F3F7B-4EA3-4749-9601-B9D879B19498
/dev/sda7  Linux filesystem             5829D354-8018-43FD-9738-B31A82C0073B
/dev/sda8  Linux swap                   F8FCB0F2-38EC-4A3C-92CB-7196DC7AEAF0
/dev/sda9  Linux filesystem             31174EC2-06E4-4963-8302-273994431B65
/dev/sda10 Linux filesystem             BC658257-DBE5-40D0-9CD1-CEC46E1913BC
/dev/sda11 Linux filesystem             E1E3A130-EA53-48B4-A130-4CF349964A41
/dev/sda12 Linux filesystem             359F6EC1-D937-43E6-A3E3-DDC8E457C0CC
/dev/sda13 Linux filesystem             82092B42-981D-4F67-977F-6A3F034B365E
/dev/sda14 Linux filesystem             278ACACC-B8CC-4169-8A79-E9812F59B035
/dev/sda15 Linux swap                   33BF80B8-A409-4AD5-B778-836974BAA8C3

Partition table entries are not in disk order.
```

I tried repacking the initramfs, checked that the resume variable is not set wrong, and only one of the two systems does this.

Comment: Also it's possible over systemd.swap: https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.swap.html